# keypad hides text view

Tags: iphone

i am placing a tableview,textview,buttons in a view as [like this](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1f91e8626a.png).

when ever i click on the textview keypad hides textview.To animate up textview i am writing the code as fallows.

```
- (void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self animateTextField:textView up:YES];
}

- (void) textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self animateTextField:textView up:NO];
}

- (void) animateTextField: (UITextView*) textView up: (BOOL) up {
    const int movementDistance = 80; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

But it does n't take any effect.

And To hide the keypad i am writing this code

```
-(void) touchesBegan :(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [mytextview resignFirstResponder];
}
```

it is also does n't take any effect.

can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For resigning keyboard;

Make a ToolBar with bar button and add an IBAction for this and set its y coordinate below the 480(screen hieght)

```
-(IBAction)hide
{
  [mytextview resignFirstResponder];

}
```

and in viewWillAppear use

```
myTextView.inputAccessoryView=tlBar;

And add two notification in viewWillAppear for keyboard

NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];


and then use these methods for Animation

-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *) note
{
    if(isAnimate)
    [self viewAnimateUpper];
}

-(void)viewAnimateUpper
{

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];

        CGRect viewFrame=self.view.frame;

        viewFrame.origin.y -=95;//according to you
        self.view.frame=viewFrame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];


}

-(void)viewAnimatedown
{

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];

        CGRect viewFrame=self.view.frame;

        viewFrame.origin.y +=95;//according to you
        self.view.frame=viewFrame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];

}
-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *) note
{
        if(isAnimate)
              {
    [self viewAnimatedown];
     }
}
```

**Edit:**

use textviewShouldBegainEditing

and in this set a boolvariable to yes if your desired textView call this method

isAnimate=YES;

Comment: Hey i use this,Then it animates when keypad raise,for all the textviews and text fields animates up.But i need only one textview

Comment: Brother then add a bool variable and set tags for your control and according to you use delegate methods of text fields and text view for adjusting. I can give a view,you need to implement according to you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a chance to see you view,since my browser says "The image cant be dispalyed,It contains errors."

So try the following options.

Chk whether you have set the delegate of the textField to the files owner.If you have set and still not working,please try the below one.Its like animating the entire view up and down on textedits.

Please make use of the below code.This works for me.What you have to do is double click the .xib file where you want to add text fields.The view along with a window containing file's owner,first responder and a view will also be opened.

Use cmd+shift+l to open the library and add another view.In your .h file add a IBOutlet for the view as IBOutlet UIView *secondview and map to the file's owner.

Now put the text fields whichever has to moved in the second view.Now the default view which will appear when open the .xib file will contain nothing.It will be blank and the controls whichever you have to display will be on the second view.

In the .m file add the second view to the main view as

```
[self.view addSubview:secondView];
```

and use this code by customizing the text field names as you wish.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    if(textField==textfield1)
    {
    [textfield1 resignFirstResponder];
    [textfield2 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if(textField== textfield2)
    {
        [textfield2 resignFirstResponder];
        [textfield3 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if(textField== textfield3)
    {
        [textfield3 resignFirstResponder];  
        [textfield4 becomeFirstResponder];

    }
    else if(textField== textfield4)
    {
        [textfield4 resignFirstResponder];

    }
    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
        CGRect viewFrame = secondView.frame;

        CGRect textFieldRect =[secondView.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
        CGRect viewRect =[secondView.window convertRect:secondView.bounds fromView:secondView];
        CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
        CGFloat numerator =midline - viewRect.origin.y- MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
        CGFloat denominator =(MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)* viewRect.size.height;
        CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;
        if (heightFraction  1.0)
        {
            heightFraction = 1.0;
        }
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        {
            animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
        }
        else
        {
            animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
        }

        viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

        [secondView setFrame:viewFrame];

        [UIView commitAnimations];

}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    CGRect viewFrame = secondView.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y +=animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [secondView setFrame:viewFrame];


    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Let me know does this worked.

Comment: To resign the keypad you can put a button over the view,set it as a customized button,write a method like this -(IBAction)resignKeyPad{[textFiled resignFirstResponder];} and put an outlet for the button in .h file and map the method to touch down event of the button and select the button in the view and under the layouts menu of the Interface Builder choose "Send to Back".This way it avoids the use of touchesBegan methods in order to resign the keypads.

Comment: Thank u sankar,But i need for textview not text field.